# How to get Alexa to play music using Pandora without saying "on Pandora"?

Tags: alexa, amazon-echo

Whenever I say **"Alexa play Metallica"**, it says that it is not found on Amazon Prime. It only works the way I want it when I say **"Alexa play Metallica *on Pandora*"**

My *Default music library* is set to *Amazon Music* and *Default station service* is set to *Pandora*. I have neither Amazon Prime music nor Spotify Premium.

How can Alexa be configured to automatically play the Metallica Pandora station whenever I say **"Alexa play Metallica"**?

*I had configured Alexa to do this previously, but have forgotten how to do it again.*

Answer (score 5):

There are instructions on Pandora's [help](https://help.pandora.com/s/article/Pandora-and-Amazon-Alexa-1519949300348?language=en_US) page, on how to set Pandora as the default Alexa music service.

> 1. Open the Alexa companion app and select “Settings.”
> 2. Select “Music and Media.”
> 3. Select the “Choose Default Music Service” button.
> 4. Select “Pandora” as the “Default station service.
>
>    By setting Pandora as your default service, users can launch stations without
>      saying “…on Pandora”.

Comment: I have already set Pandora as the "Default station service". However I still need to end the Alexa command with "... station" or "... on Pandora"

Comment: It doesn't work for me! It used to work when I used Pandora but then I switched to Amazon music. I didn't like that Too bad Amazon doesn't permit talking to them. Now I have to say Pandora, if I don't it plays Amazon music.